# underscore sortby specify a few items

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I'm using `underscore`s `sortBy()` to sort an `array` of strings. But I want to sort a couple (hard-coded) strings earlier than the rest - I'll be displaying the output to the user and it's more natural to put relevant strings up front.

E.g.: I want `name` and `type` to appear first and second, respectively, followed by everything else in alphabetical order.

Given:

```
["above", "name", "below", "foo", "type", "bar"]
```

I want:

```
["name", "type", "above", "bar", "below", "foo"]
```

I know I can provide an `iteratee` to `sortBy()` but it's a little unclear to me how I would cleanly and consistently get the desired behavior.

I tried:

```
const relevantSort = function(key) {
    if (key === 'name') { return [0, key]; }
    if (key === 'type') { return [1, key]; }
    return [2, key];
}
```

(I know there are ways to tighten that up, but that's orthogonal to my question).

This results in in a stably-sorted, *correctly*-sorted array... but this would break down if I had a bunch of hard-codes and eventually returned `[10, key]` somewhere, because of Javascript array sorting coercing numbers into strings.

Is there some clearer, cleaner, less fragile way to get my desired behavior?

EDIT:
Also, may not have been clear from above - I don't know the contents of the array beforehand, and I don't know if `name` or `type` will always be there (nor at what `index` if they even do exist).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

**UPDATED**

```
var array = ["above", "name", "below", "foo", "type", "bar"];

if(array.indexOf('type') > -1) {
    array.splice(1, 0, array.splice(array.indexOf('type'), 1)[0]);
}

if(array.indexOf('name') > -1) {
    array.splice(0, 0, array.splice(array.indexOf('name'), 1)[0]);
}
```

Comment: That truncates the array to the first 2 elements? I guess I'll add: I don't know the order of these items beforehand, and I don't always know if `name` or `type` will be in there. I just want them first if they *do* exist.

Comment: Ok, this is a little less clearer, but it would do. The order shouldn't matter, even when the array is already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how "underscore" works exactly but this pure javascript code might help you out.
This is also kind of hard-coded but it may work for you.

```
var arr = ["above", "name", "below", "foo", "type", "bar"];

['name', 'type'].concat(arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item !== "name" && item !== "type";
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a > b;
}));
```

If you are looking for something like `["name", "type", 10, 11, 140, "above", "bar", "below", "foo"]` remove callback function from sort since it will give you result with words first and numbers after.

Comment: The issue with that is I don't *always* want to add `name` and `type` into the array. But *if* they are there, then I want them first. So I would need to check if they were there, then filter them out, then add them in at the beginning - I was hoping for something cleaner (though I'm ending up with Schwartzian transforms as my solution, which is debatably less readable...)

Comment: I'm not sure how familiar you are with functional concepts of programming, but I guess you are since you are using underscore, and I can say that programming is all about transforming and processing data. This could be a solution to your problem, only edge case is repeated values 'name' and 'type'.

arr.filter(function(item) {
 return item === "name" || item === "type"
}).concat(arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item !== "name" && item !== "type";
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a > b;
}));

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

```
var array = ["above", "name", "below", "foo", "type", "bar"]; 

var hardcoded_array = ["name", "type"]; 

var difference = _.difference(array, hardcoded_array); 

var value_exist_array = _.intersection(array, hardcoded_array);

var sorted_array = _.sortBy(difference, function(value) {
       return value; 
});

console.log(value_exist_array.concat(sorted_array)); // ["name", "type", "above", "bar", "below", "foo"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom sort function with an order object specifying the word and with values specifying the order. Word with low value will come before the words with high values in the sorted array.

```js
const order = {'name' : 1, 'type' : 2};

function sortArray(order, arr) {
  return arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    if(order[a] && order[b])
      return order[a] - order[b];
    else if(order[a] || order[b])
      return order[a] || order[b];
    else
      return a.localeCompare(b);   
  });
}

console.log(sortArray(order, ["above", "name", "below", "foo", "type", "bar"]));
console.log(sortArray(order, ["above", "below", "foo", "type", "bar"]));
console.log(sortArray(order, ["above", "below", "foo", "bar"]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```